# Should I be concerned about this rusted support post in a new house?

Tags: beam, support

I’m under contract for a newly built home and noticed a rusty support post in the basement.  There are some other small issues with the home too but this one has me concerned. It’s just under a year old, never lived in.

Is this a serious red flag?

[image]

Comment: I would find that quite concerning. I would spend the $150-$300 for a qualified home inspector and insist on any problems of this scale be properly repaired before closing. You _do_ have an inspection clause in your contract, don't you?

Comment: First, that’s an odd shaped beam. I’d check to see if they used the correct shaped beam. Second, if that represents 1 year of rust, you’ll have problems in 3-4 years. Third, I’d contact the Building Department and ask to see the “sign off” on the Permit and ask them to inspect it to see if it’s the wrong beam. Fourth, I’d notify contractor IN WRITING that the beam is not acceptable because of the rust and shape of the beam.

Comment: I think it is a support post or lolly column, as in the picture is taken looking down at the floor and those are control joints in the concrete floor...

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. I've taken the liberty of rotating the picture, since this seems to be a _post_ (vertical) not a _beam_ (horizontal). If my understanding was incorrect please revert the edit (or let us know in the comments and someone will take care of it for you).

Comment: psaxton - Yes, that pic was actually taken during the home inspection. The report will be issued within the next day, but seeing that rust on the post really has me concerned. Especially since this is new construction.  There appear to be a few water stains on the concrete floor as well, but as the inspector mentioned, there could have been a power failure and the sump pump didn’t function for a bit. Thank you for your response!

Comment: I would say it probably goes along with the water marks on the Sheetrock. I would wire brush it and paint it, would I be concerned NO. I have steel Collins standing in water for decades prior to needing repair.

Comment: Too many off-topic comments here. That's the floor, not a beam. That's not an expansion joint, it's a control joint, and it was placed there _because_ the post is there, causing a weakness in the slab. The post position is irrelevant. Let's try to stay on topic.

Comment: In my experience this type of post isn't buried in concrete, at least not to that level. There's a solid steel leg that usually extends into the slab, with the tubular body resting safely above. I'd be somewhat concerned about that post being weakened by corrosion over a couple decades.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is reasonable to be concerned. However, I would not panic.

I would contact an engineer and have it inspected by a competent professional.

If it is determined that it is just surface rust you should be able to grind it off with a wire wheel and a drill, then apply a rust inhibitor primer and paint it to prevent further rust issues.

If it is a structural issue you would need to support either side of it, relieve the load and replace it with a new post that is rated for the determined load. I would most definitely hire a contractor to do this unless you have extensive experience in carpentry and framing.